# .htaccess RewriteRule направляет когда папку сущустиеще

Tags: .htaccess

добрый день у мне сайту я заметил если заходит 
site.ru/test 
сущустиеще папку перенаправляет 
site.ru/test/?go=test

а если заходит
site.ru/test/ - работает нормально

в .htaccess написино

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)/?$ /index.php?go=$1 [L,QSA]
>
> RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-*]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-*]+)/?$
>   index.php?go=$1&go2=$2 [NC,QSA]

Comment: Улыбнул ваш русский. Так в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: в чем ваш вопрос заключается?

Comment: можно сделать так,  test.ru/test - не направлялся site.ru/test/?go=test ?

Comment: Да, удалите эти 3 строки.

Comment: тогда  .htaccess не будет отправить запрос на index.php go=test

Comment: я сделал пример для вам http://file.sim.az/test заходите сюда и сюда http://file.sim.az/test/